# Which option I need to compile php code with HHVM

Tags: php, c++, facebook, compilation, hiphop

`hhvm --hphp -thhbc -o some_dir file1.php file2.php`
This is pre-compile option which is example in hiphop for php github wiki.
I would like to output PHP code to C++ code with hiphop VM.
Can anyone tell me how to get it done? Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's what you want to do? HHVM has superceded the transpilation to C++ and then compilation with a JIT. Now you "just run" the code instead, which they've managed to now make [even faster](http://www.hhvm.com/blog/875/wow-hhvm-is-fast-too-bad-it-doesnt-run-my-code)

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

HHVM does not support converting PHP to C++. HHVM works by JIT compiling PHP code into x64 machine code on the fly. For details on how to use HHVM to run PHP programs, check out the following:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-PHP-programs-with-HHVM

http://www.hhvm.com/blog/113/getting-wordpress-running-on-hhvm

http://www.j4ml.com/2013/09/how-to-use-hhvm-running-wordpress.html

HPHPc (HHVM's predecessor) worked by converting PHP to C++, but HPHPc has since been retired. For details on why HPHPc was retired, see

http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP#History_Before_HHVM .

(Edit: Provided an additional link.)

Comment: I think the OP is asking about how to compile the source into Repo Authoritative mode.

Answer (score 1):

There are docs on compiling to RepoAuth mode:

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Performance-Tuning#easy-way